# How filter data from database according alphabetical month name

Tags: mysql

I want to filter data from the database according to alphabetically month name, if I have date formated in the database like this: `2019-02-21`.

I have put a screenshot of my data table structure here:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't understand you, please clarify your question. and make sure you did look for the answer.

Comment: The question is unclear, at least to me. Please [edit] it and add you table structure, some sample data and the result you'd like to get for this sample.

Comment: I think my question is very clear but I do not understand why are you not able to get my question.i have added data table structure screenshot column name "start_date" now I want to search data according to alphabetically month name like "march, April" but in my database date formate is that- 2019-02-21

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following using [`MONTHNAME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MONTHNAME(column_name) = 'February'
```

... or you can use the following using [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%M') = 'February'
```